# XCode console weird char

Tags: xcode, console, char

Does anyone know what this is and what does it mean?

[image: weird char]

My XCode version is: Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Comment: Looks like [BALLOT BOX WITH X](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2612/index.htm)

Comment: Yes, it seems it is, thank you. I'd like to know why it is displayed.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer but just a comment :)